# What is the name of this construction of quantum things?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, terminology, category-theory

Let $E$ be a set, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of maps $E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that "carries all the information on $E$", that is, the map $x \in E \mapsto (f(x))_{f \in \mathcal{F}}$ is injective.

Let us call "classical things" the elements of $E$. Let us call "a representation of quantum things" a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and a map $\widehat{ \cdot } : \mathcal{F} \rightarrow Obs(\mathcal{H})$, where we denote by $Obs(\mathcal{H})$ the set of self-adjoint operators on $\mathcal{H}$, such that the map $\hat{ \cdot }$ satisfies some conditions.

*Example 1:* Let $E$ be $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of maps $w \mapsto \langle v,w\rangle$ for $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ carries all the information on $\mathbb{R}^3$ since a vector is uniquely defined by the data consisting of the scalar products with all vectors.

Then every vector $\phi$ in $\mathcal{H}$ can be seen as a state of a "quantum vector", to be thought as having coordinate $a$ in the $v$-direction if, when measuring the $\widehat{( w\mapsto \langle v,w\rangle)}$ observable, one gets $a$.

As a particular case, spin $\frac{1}{2}$ can be considered as a kind of a "quantum vector with all coordinates that whenever measured, give a result in $\{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$".

*Example 2:* the phase space of a classical $1$-dimensional particle is $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, and one can consider the set of maps carrying all the information to be $\mathcal{F} := \{q,p\} = \{(x,y) \mapsto x, (x,y) \mapsto y\}$.

To this classical representation corresponds the quantum representation where $\hat{q} := Q$ is the position operator, and $\hat{p} := P$ is the momentum operator.

My question is the following: I think this definition probably already exists, maybe in categorical terms, maybe in the particular case where $E$ is a manifold with enough structure. I would like to know the name of this construction; that is, the name of the general abstract framework where the two examples fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mathematical concept OP might be looking for is [*quantization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(physics)), which applies to any process turning a classical *mechanical* system into a quantum one. The emphasis on mechanical is important, as the symplectic structure of phase space is often a necessary data for the quantization process.

For specific methods of quantization for finite dimensional phase spaces (ie regular quantum mechanics and not field theory), which are well understood mathematically, you can look up [deformation quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(physics)) and [geometric quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization).

However, those quantization processes start with a phase space (ie a symplectic manifold), so cannot be applied to example 1. In particular, I don't think finite dimensional Hilbert spaces can be obtained this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear what you're asking but

> spin $\frac{1}{2}$ can be considered as a kind of a "quantum vector
> with all coordinates having values in {$±\frac{1}{2}$}"

is a misleading way to think about spin, at least in the sense of a "quantum vector with all coordinates having values in {$±\frac{1}{2}$}".

The classic counterexample is to consider three spins, each one at an angle of $2\pi/3$ w/r to its neighbour.  As vectors in the plane, they geometrically sum to $0$, but you cannot take three values of $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ and sum them to $0$, thus raising serious doubts about your previous claim on having values in {$±\frac{1}{2}$}.

Comment: Sure, sure! You are pointing out the fact that usually, one cannot ask the $\widehat{f}$'s to commute.

Comment: well... I'm pointing to the fact that "taking values in $\{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$" doesn't make much sense...  You might want to say something more nuanced like "there is a basis in which the possible outcomes are strictly restricted to $\{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$" but without the qualifier you will run into all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Ok, I agree. If I change "taking values in $\{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$" by "whenever measured, give a result in $\{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$", do you find the sentence better?

Comment: yeah something like this.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if we put a [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) [structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) on both the set $E$ and the maps $f:E\to \mathbb{C}$ (together with a notion of open sets and continuity), then OP's construction is part of the mathematical topics of [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis) and [operator theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_theory).